# Why std::shared_ptr doesn't work with base template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

First let me show you the inheritance structure:

```
template <class Type>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual bool verify() const = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base<int> {

public:
    Derived() : Base<int>::Base() {}
    virtual bool verify() const override;
};
```

So, the base class for `Derived` is `Base<int>`.

I'm trying to define a template overload of the "|" operator:

```
template<class Type>
std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> operator|(std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> p1, std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>> p2)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Base<Type>>();
}
```

And, if I write something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> d;
std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> bInt;
auto result = d | bInt;
```

I'll get an error like:

> C++ missing "|" operator corresponding to these operands:
> std::shared_ptr<Derived> | std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>

But, if I explicitly specify the type of the base class when overloading, everything will work correctly:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> operator|(std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> p1, std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> p2)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>();
}
```

How can I make the templated overload work?

Comment: Template deduction only works on the exact type, without conversion. Your operator would require a conversion from `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` to `std::shared_ptr<Base<int>>`. When you specify the type explicitly there is no deduction, so it works.

Comment: The code is a bit odd because all the shared_ptr objects all hold `nullptr`.

Comment: @Eljay all is ok, I left ptrs not initialized to simplify my code. In real case they're initialized ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to either specify operator for a Derived class, or to save both of your variables in the pointer of Base:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
std::shared_ptr<Base<int>> bInt;
auto res = d | bInt;
```